# I am using pm2 and ecosystem file for its configuration. Auto restart apps on file change is not working

Tags: node.js, watch

I am trying to debug node app using below config(launch.json) in VS code:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach by Process ID",
            "processId": "${command:PickProcess}",
            "port": 9229
        },
```

and the command to run is  : pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --only development.

My ecosystem config file looks like for development mode:

```
apps: [
    {
      name: "development",
      script: "./app.js",
      node_args : ["--inspect-brk"],
      watch: true,
      ignore_watch : ["node_modules", "logs"],
      watch_options: {
        "followSymlinks": false
      },
      .....
      .....
      .....

      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "development"
      }
    }]
```

My changes are not reflecting even though , I am using watch: true.

Comment: With the below command in package.json file , I am able to debug my app. 
"debug": "pm2 start ./app.js --node-args=--inspect-brk --watch"

Answer (score 0):

With the below command in package.json file , I am able to debug my app. "debug": "pm2 start ./app.js --node-args=--inspect-brk --watch"